# NSOulineView header cell font

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm trying to reduce the font size of the Header Cell in a `NSOutlineView` (source-list view-based). The problem is that using IB doesn't work for me (both modifying the font for `NSTextField` and `NSTextFieldCell`).

The views are returned by `outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:` using `makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:`

Any ideas?

Comment: Please be sure to post the answer below, and remove it from the question section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These steps solved the problem.

1) Select the `NSOutlineView` in IB.

2) In the `Size Inspector` select `Automatic` for `Size Style`. If it is already selected, deselect and select it again (XCode bug?)

Now you can modify the font for the `NSTextFieldCell` (Header Cells and Data Cells) using IB.